# Как работает Redis при одновременном доступе нескольких клиентов?

Tags: redis

Первый клиент (локальный) пишет в список редис строку 50 байт 20 раз в секунду.
Допустим набрали 200 000 строк = 10 мегабайт
Второй клиент пытается получить первые 100 000 строк.
Передача через инет займет какое-то время.
Что в это время происходит с первым клиентом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все операции в Redis атомарны.

Версионности в Redis, насколько я знаю, нет.

Следовательно, будет блокировка: пока один клиент читает данные, второй будет ждать.

---

Цитата:

> пишет в список

Если речь именно о *списках* - List, то *общий* размер списка не будет влиять на работу клиентов: один клиент пишет данные в список, другой клиент читает. Как я уже сказал ранее, одному из клиентов приходится ждать, пока завершится операция другого. Но общий размер *списка* не влияет на это, ведь другой клиент будет читать за раз одну короткую строку размером 50 байт, а не всё содержимое списка разом.

Я попытался проиллюстрировть это следующим кодом на C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace ConAppRedis
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,allowAdmin=true");
            redis.GetServer("localhost", 6379).FlushAllDatabases();

            var are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            const int count = 10000;
            RedisKey key = "key";

            var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
                var list = new List<string>();
                are.WaitOne();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(db.ListRightPop(key));
                }
            });

            var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
                var s = new string('a', 25); // 50 bytes

                for (int i = 0; i < count * 2; i++)
                {
                    db.ListLeftPush(key, s);
                    if (i == count)
                    {
                        are.Set();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(db.ListLength(key));
            });

            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаются две задачи (клиента): первая сперва ждёт разрешения на старт (его выдаст вторая задача, записав половину данных), потом начинает считывать данные.

Вторая задача пишет данные в список. В конце эта задача получает текущий размер списка и выводит его. Значение каждый раз разное, что естественно, и равно где-то 10055.

То есть к тому времени когда вторая задача заканчивает записывать 20000 значений, первая уже успела прочитать почти половину. Следовательно, они обращались к серверу по очереди совместно.

---

А вот если бы речь шла о конкатенации одной строки с помощью APPEND, что приводило бы к её увеличению, то вторая задача довольно долго ждала бы, когда первая будет получать её полностью за раз (иначе никак).